# Editing output of collections.Counter in Python

Tags: python-2.7, counter

New Python learner here and I'm trying to figure out how to get the desired output format as instructed from my tutorial specs. Basically I am to key in any characters (e.g. asjndkfsdhfbhdbhssassasa82) and the program is to calculate the top 5 most frequent characters. I am able to get the desired result thus far, however I am unable to print it according to my lab specs.

For now, my output is

(character):(frequency)

(character):(frequency)

.

.

.

How do I make it such that it appears as (character):(frequency), (character):(frequency), etc.?

```
import sys
import collections

charInput = sys.argv[1].lower()
charInputTemp = list(charInput)    #Convert entire string into individual characters

charInputArray = []

for char in charInput:
    charInputArray.append(char)    #Add each character to array for sorting     

charInputArray.sort()

letters = collections.Counter(charInputArray)     #Get number of occurrence of a character

for letter, count in letters.most_common(5):    #Get 5 most frequent character
    print '%s:%d' % (letter, count)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
import sys
import collections

charInput = sys.argv[1].lower()
charInputTemp = list(charInput)    #Convert entire string into individual characters

charInputArray = []

for char in charInput:
    charInputArray.append(char)    #Add each character to array for sorting     

charInputArray.sort()

letters = collections.Counter(charInputArray)   #Get number of occurrence of a character

output = []
for letter, count in letters.most_common(5):    #Get 5 most frequent character
    output.append(str(letter)+":"+str(count))
print (",".join(output))
```